# How can we calculate risk and return for a time series data set?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
import pandas as pd
 
# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Year': 2020, 'Airport':2000, 'Casino':5000, 'Stadium':9000}, 
       {'Year': 2019, 'Airport':3000, 'Casino':4000, 'Stadium':12000},
       {'Year': 2018, 'Airport':5000, 'Casino':9000, 'Stadium':10000},
       {'Year': 2017, 'Airport':5000, 'Casino':10000, 'Stadium':15000}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df = df.set_index(['Year'])
df
```

[image]

Now, I am trying to calculate the return and risk of each 'asset'. Here is the code that I am testing.

I found the code sample here.

https://tirthajyoti.github.io/Notebooks/Portfolio_optimization.html

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cvxpy import *

symbols = df.columns

# convert daily stock prices into daily returns
returns = df.pct_change().T


r = np.asarray(np.mean(returns, axis=1))
r = np.nan_to_num(r)

C = np.asmatrix(np.cov(returns))
C = np.nan_to_num(C)


# print expected returns and risk
for j in range(len(symbols)):
    print ('%s: Exp ret = %f, Risk = %f' %(symbols[j],r[j], C[j,j]**0.5))
```

[image]

```
# Number of variables
n = len(symbols)

# The variables vector
x = Variable(n)

# The minimum return
req_return = 0.02

# The return
ret = r.T*x

# The risk in xT.Q.x format
risk = quad_form(x, C)

# The core problem definition with the Problem class from CVXPY
#prob = Problem(Minimize(risk), [sum(x)==1, ret >= req_return, x >= 0])
prob = Problem(Minimize(risk), [sum(x)==1, ret >= req_return, x >= 0, x <= 0.4])

try:
    prob.solve()
    print ("Optimal portfolio")
    print ("----------------------")
    for s in range(len(symbols)):
       print (" Investment in {} : {}% of the portfolio".format(symbols[s],round(100*x.value[s],2)))
    print ("----------------------")
    print ("Exp ret = {}%".format(round(100*ret.value,2)))
    print ("Expected risk    = {}%".format(round(100*risk.value**0.5,2)))
except:
    print ("Error")
```

[image]

For some reason, which I don't fully understand, the risk is always zero. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `numpy` or `pandas` but I can tell you this line `C = np.asmatrix(np.cov(returns))` is leading to a matrix of `nan` values. The cause of this seems to be that the `2020` column in your `returns` dataframe contains `nan` values and `numpy` just fills in a `nan` for covariance when one is part of the equation. Maybe change that line to `C = np.asmatrix(np.cov(returns.drop(2020, axis=1))`?

Comment: You are right! I made the change you recommended and it works now! Thanks for showing me that!!!